# Web essential incorrectly minify javascript in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net-mvc, minify, visual-studio-2017-build-tools

Web essential incorrectly minify javascript in Visual Studio 2017.
It works well for css.
IS there any other tool to minify js in visual studio 2018 .net core 2.1

Comment: There is to much online tools to do this just seach on google but if you are developing at real time a suggest usgin **webpack**

Comment: I've been using Web Essentials to compile and minify js without much problems, do you mind sharing what specific scenario causes the error and what are the error messages if any? I'd like to know so I can watch out for it.